# iPad videoPlayerDidFinishPlaying callback method not responding

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am facing a problem in ipad video incorporating. My code works fine I mean it plays the video, but once the video reaches to its end. The callback method is not called.

This method is called when play video button is pressed.

```
-(IBAction) playVideo : (id) sender
{
  [self initPlayingVideo:@"toyVid.mp4"];
}
```

This method handles the playing of video.

```
-(void) initPlayingVideo: (NSString *) videoFile
{
  NSString *moviePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoFile];

  theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];
  theMovie.moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
  theMovie.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;


  [self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
  addObserver:self
  selector:@selector(videoPlayerDidFinishPlaying
  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
  object:theMovie];

  videoPlayer = [theMovie moviePlayer];
  [videoPlayer play];
}
```

This is the callback method.

```
-(void) videoPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (NSNotification*)aNotification
{
  theMovie = [aNotification object];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:theMovie.moviePlayer];
  [videoPlayer stop];
  [theMovie.moviePlayer release];
  [videoPlayer release];
  [theMovie.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Where I am doing mistake? Please guide.

Regards
Ranjan

Comment: You may consider to put your codes in code sections: just place four spaces before your codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you miss the : and ) in your selector? I guess ) may be your typo otherwise you cannot compile your codes. Your selection takes one parameter. It should be:

```
selector:@selector(videoPlayerDidFinishPlaying:)
```

That will match to your instance method. I guess you don't have one without parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David.

The listener function is as under. colon(:) and closing parenthesis ")" is there.

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
  addObserver:self
  selector:@selector(videoPlayerDidFinishPlaying:)
  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
  object:theMovie];